# 'get' data to php page on WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been following on some youtube tutorials about php and had no problem executing my code on xampp, but now that I am trying to build the same functionality into a WordPress website, I can't get the 'get' data to feed into the same page it's located on:

```
<?php require 'sqlconnectscript.php';  ?>

    <form action="retrieve_page.php" method="GET">
    To get started, choose a genre:
    <select name="genre">
    <option value="Rock">Rock</option>
    <option value="Blues">BLues</option>
    </select><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">

</form>

<?php

if(isset($_GET['genre'])&&!empty($_GET['genre'])) {
$genre = strtolower($_GET['genre']); 

    echo 'OK';
}
?>
```

In the xampp version submitting one or other option with this code works fine but in WP when I press submit the form comes back with a 404 error telling me it can't find retrieve_page.php - but that's where I'm starting from. Please help :)

Comment: please add code snippets

Comment: Oh I did but they didn't comment out? Sorry this is my first post here

Comment: I think you need to create a rest API to run get calls in for WordPress?

Comment: @marmeladze I updated the code.

Comment: is that file `retrieve_page.php`?

Answer (score 0):

Please change the form action to #

```
<form action="#" method="GET">
```